# Unsubscribe MobilePush Contacts with Automation

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest, contact, mobilepush, unsubscriber

I need to unsubscribe multiple Contacts from Push Messages with the help of external attributes. It is to be done within an Automation. The only way I see I can do this is the following:

1. Get ContactKey for the contacts that should be unsubscribe.
2. Retrieve MobilePush attributes with: https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/attributes/search (this is since I need to have all the DeviceIDs for the Contact)
3. Update Data Extension with MobilePush attributes
4. Import to MobilePush from Data Extension with status Inactive

It would be so much easier if the _PushAddress data view had the ContactKey. But unfortunately, it only has the ContactID for some weird reason.

Is there anyone out there that have another suggestion? Or at least have some input on mine.